# Using case class to add unknown columns as null

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am creating a new dataframe (set by case class) with an input dataframe that may have less/different number of columns than the existing one. I am trying to use case class to set the value of the non-existing as null.

I am using this case class to drive the new dataframe to be created.

The input dataframe (incomingDf) may not have the all variables field that are set as null above.

```
case class existingSchema(source_key: Int
                        , sequence_number: Int
                        , subscriber_id: String
                        , subscriber_ssn: String
                        , last_name: String
                        , first_name: String
                        , variable1: String = null
                        , variable2: String = null
                        , variable3: String = null
                        , variable4: String = null
                        , variable5: String = null
                        , source_date: Date
                        , load_date: Date
                        , file_name_String: String)

val incomingDf = spark.table("raw.incoming")

val formattedDf = incomingDf.as[existingSchema].toDF()
```

This throws an error at compile time.

The new schema of the formattedDf is expected to have the same schema as the case class existingSchema.

```
incomingDf.printSchema
```

```
root
 |-- source_key: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- sequence_number: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- subscriber_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- subscriber_ssn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- variable1: string (nullable=true)
 |-- variable3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- load_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- file_name_string: string (nullable = true)
```

Compile Error:

```
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
    val formattedDf = incomingDf.as[existingSchema].toDF()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                     ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
one error found                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 FAILED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

* What went wrong:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Execution failed for task ':compileScala'.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
> Compilation failed
```

Update:
I added the code line:

```
import incomingDf.sparkSession.implicits._
```

and the compile is fine.

I get the following error now in the run time:

```
19/04/17 14:37:56 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`variable2`' given input columns: [variable1, variable3, sequence_number, last_name, first_name, file_name_string, subscriber_id, load_date, source_key];
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`variable2`' given input columns: [variable1, variable3, sequence_number, last_name, first_name, file_name_string, subscriber_id, load_date, source_key];
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
```

Comment: please run `incomingDf.printSchema` and post here, also add the exception including stack trace

Comment: added it above in the OP.

Comment: ... did you add `import spark.implicits._` as the error suggest?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added the implicits import, I am getting runtime error now, updated in OP.

Comment: you can see from the printed schema that raw.incoming table does not have the schema of your case class.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to map the incomingDf to the case class existingSchema with the missing fields as null as part of my problem.

Comment: I get it now, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing schema is missing some String fields of the case class. You just need to add them explicitly:

```
val formattedDf = Seq("variable2", "variable4", "variable5")
  .foldLeft(incomingDf)((df, col) => {
    df.withColumn(col, lit(null.asInstanceOf[String]))
  }).as[existingSchema].toDF()
```

A more general solution would be to infer the missing fields.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. I inferred the missing field names, luckily all the missing fields will be String.

Comment: Works like a charm, I added:

val targetSchema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[existingSchema].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
val missingFields = targetSchema .fieldNames.diff(incomingDf.schema.fieldNames).toSeq

to add the missing fields.

Also change to lit(null).cast("String") to set the null values as stringtype.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to specifically define your DF schema. For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val newSchema: StructType = StructType(Array(
  StructField("nested_array", ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType)), true),
  StructField("numbers", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("text", StringType, true)
))

// Given a DataFrame df...
val combinedSchema = StructType(df.schema ++ newSchema)
val resultRDD = ... // here, process df to add rows or whatever and get the result as an RDD
                    // you can get an RDD as simply as df.rdd
val outDf = sparkSession.createDataFrame(resultRDD, combinedSchema)
```

The third member of the `[StructField][1]` argument ensures that the newly created fields are nullable. The default is true, so you don't really have to add that, but I include it for clarity, since the whole purpose of using this method is to create a specifically nullable field.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want to be able to keep my schema intact because I will be adding partitions to an existing hive table. The combinedSchema you mentioned above will be a new schema everytime I run it.

Comment: extracting an `RDD` from the `DataFrame` is not acceptable in many cases, mainly in infrastructure code when filters are expected to be pushed down to the data source layer.

Comment: @shay__ Modification of schema in place is prone to break when you start adding new features or functionality, in my experience. If you take an uncertain input, I find that it is best to immediately set it to a definitive schema (and also definitively re-partition the input, while you are at it).

Comment: we have no argue about that, however it has nothing to do with falling back to RDD.

Comment: @shay__ Well, my perspective mostly comes from my code being recently converted from 1.6, where you had to go back to RDD to do stuff like this; so this is just something that works. I haven't done it another way.

Comment: oh I see :) indeed my perspective is 2.x where converting from DF to RDD and back is highly discouraged since it breaks the lineage and forces a serialization of the data, but even worse it denies you from pushing down user level filters. in the majority of cases it is better to use the DF api than falling back to RDD and back.